# 1expected bytes, str found when trying to connect to postresql in Google Functions

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I have not been able to connect to postgresql from google functions. This is the code - I'm following these instructions https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions. The actual output of my program is **1expected bytes, str found**, as it manages to do the first print before raising the Exception.

I haven't even been able to get a more explicit error than this. Any ideas would be very much welcome :-).

```
import os
import sqlalchemy
import pg8000

def hello_world(request):
    output = ''
    try:

        # Remember - storing secrets in plaintext is potentially unsafe. Consider using
        # something like https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/overview to help keep
        # secrets secret.
        db_user = $DB_USER
        db_pass = $PASS
        db_name = $DB_NAME
        db_socket_dir = os.environ.get("DB_SOCKET_DIR", "/cloudsql")
        cloud_sql_connection_name = $CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME

        pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            # Equivalent URL:
            # postgres+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>
            #                         ?unix_sock=<socket_path>/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
            sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
                drivername="postgres+pg8000",
                username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
                password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
                database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
                query={
                    "unix_sock": "%s/%s/.s.PGSQL.5432" % (
                        db_socket_dir,  # e.g. "/cloudsql"
                        cloud_sql_connection_name)  # i.e "<PROJECT-NAME>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>"
                }
            ),
            # ... Specify additional properties here.
        )
        output += '1'

        pool.connect()

        output += '2'
        return output
    except Exception as e:
        output += str(e)
        return output
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be running into this issue of compatibility between SQLAlchemy and the latest version of pg8000: https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000/issues/53

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. The parameters need to be bytes, so if db_user = "user", for example, I need to change that to db_user = b"user"